# Update input field total from variable number of input fields in Vue2

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have variable number of input fields for product quantity input generating from API response that takes number as input. I need to update the total price for each items and subtotal for all the items once user changes the input field value.

Here is what i am trying
data:

```
 "productList": [
                {
                    "id": 27,
                    "product_id": "2362",
                    "product_name": "nengra",
                    "unit": "box",
                    "minimum_order": "1",
                    "unit_price": "890",
                    "photo_url": "http://45.114.85.21:11011/micro_product/mv8gigsx2e_7a4i2twgv6.jpg"
                },
                {
                    "id": 29,
                    "product_id": "2365",
                    "product_name": "nengra",
                    "unit": "box",
                    "minimum_order": "1",
                    "unit_price": "890",
                    "photo_url": "http://45.114.85.21:11011/micro_product/qdmiugpabf_4ojvtkryym.jpg"
                }
    ]
```

template:

```
<div v-for="{{products in productList}}" :key="products.product_id">
    <input type="number" v-model="products.qty" v-on:change="updateCart" >
<p>{{products.productsTotal}}</p>
</div>
    <p>{{subTotal}}</p>
```

Script:

```
 data(){
    return{
      qty:[],
      cartID: null,
      productList: [],
      total: 0,
      subtotal: 0,
      productTotal: 0
    }
  },
  methods: {
    updateCart: function (){
        this.products.productTotal = this.products.qty * this.productList.price
    }
  }
```

I am very newbee in Vue2 Please help me to sort it out. Thanks

Comment: `this.products` is `undefined`. `subTotal` is undefined. Please make a [mcve] like codesandbox and try to run the code you'll see the errors in console.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a computed property like this for `subTotal`:

```
computed: {
    subTotal: function () {
      return this.productList.reduce(
        (p, np) => p.productTotal + np.productTotal
      );
    },
  },
```

Pass a reference like `v-on:change="updateCart(product)"` to clicked product to update it's values:

```
methods: {
    updateCart: function (product) {
      product.productTotal = Number(product.qty) * Number(product.unit_price);
    },
 },
```

Every time we update the `product.productTotal` here, `subTotal` will automatically update since it is a computed property.

[image: Edit nice-http-0nt6c]

Side note: I've added `productTotal` property to each product. If your data doesn't contain it, you can add it manually in API success callback before setting the data.